# <apex:commandLink> in VFP doesnt recognize my controller method, Why is that?

Tags: class, commandbutton, commandlink

i'm trying to understand why the  action "**processApproveButton**" gives me an error in VFP of unlnown method, and i cant save it??

heres the code:
**Controller:**

```
global class CandidatesTabs {

    public void processApproveButton(String conId){

          //The method functionality
    }           

    webService static String processApprove(String conId){
            //webservice method that i need
    }


}
```

**VFP:**

```
    <apex:page controller="CandidatesTabs">
        <apex:pageBlock >
                   <apex:pageBlockTable id="agrileverCandidates" value="{!contacts}" var="c"  > 


                           <apex:column headerValue="Reject">
                               <apex:form>
                                    <apex:commandLink action="{!processApproveButton}" value="Save" id="theCommandLink"/>
                               </apex:form>
                           </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>  
            </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

**Any solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods bind with visualforce can not have argument in it. Here you are passing `conid`.

**The solution would be:**

```
global class CandidatesTabs {

    public String conId {get;set;}
    public void processApproveButton(){

          // Do some thing with conid
          //The method functionality
    }           

    webService static String processApprove(String conId){
            //webservice method that i need
    }


}
```

Page (added `<apex:param/>`):

```
<apex:page controller="CandidatesTabs">
        <apex:pageBlock >
                   <apex:pageBlockTable id="agrileverCandidates" value="{!contacts}" var="c"  > 


                           <apex:column headerValue="Reject">
                               <apex:form>
                                    <apex:commandLink action="{!processApproveButton}" value="Save" id="theCommandLink">
                                      <apex:param name="conId" assignTo="{!conId}" value="{!conId}"/>
         <apex:commandLink/>
                               </apex:form>
                           </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>  
            </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

I will recommend to read about `<apex:param>` how we can use it to pass values from page to controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your `processApproveButton` method expects one `String` parameter.

When you call it from your VF page using a `commandLink`, you don't send any parameter.

Comment: thanx @Martin Lezer, how can i pass a ID string?

Comment: You can read the @Ashwani's answer. He helps you passing the ID.